# Sum price from products to order

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order my orders with the total price that it gets from products table. And show the customer details with it. This is how my tables look like:

Orders table

| order_id | customer_id | date_order_placed | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20001 | 1 | 2022-03-11 | Unpaid |

order products table

| product_order_id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20001 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 20001 | 2 | 1 |

Products table

| product_id | name | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | This is an apple | 15 |
| 2 | Pear | This is a pear | 30 |

Customers table

| customer_id | first_name | last_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | johndoe@email.com |

This is my SQL I tried

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN orders_products USING (order_id) 
LEFT JOIN products USING (product_id) 
LEFT JOIN customers USING (customer_id) 
WHERE order_id = 20001 
ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

The result I get is this and what I want I also described in the snippet

```css
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!--- CSS BY W3schools -->
<h3>Result i get</h3>
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Order id</th>
    <th>Date placed</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Total price</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20001</td>
    <td>2022-03-11</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>&euro;15</td>
    <td>Unpaid</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>20001</td>
    <td>2022-03-11</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>&euro;30</td>
    <td>Unpaid</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Result i want</h3>
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Order id</th>
    <th>Date placed</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Total price</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20001</td>
    <td>2022-03-11</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>&euro;45</td>
    <td>Unpaid</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So instead that the orders with the same order id are invidual i want to add the prices of the same order and make it one total price i already tried this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orders_products USING (order_id) 
LEFT JOIN products sum(price) as total_price USING (product_id) 
LEFT JOIN customers USING (customer_id) 
WHERE order_id > ? 
ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `SUM` on `products.price` * `order_products.quantity` and `GROUP BY` on `order_products.order_id`

```
SELECT
    SUM(products.price * order_products.quantity) AS total_order_price,
    orders.*,
    customers.*
FROM
    orders
    LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.order_id = order_products.order_id
    LEFT JOIN products ON order_products.product_id = products.product_id
    LEFT JOIN customers USING orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
WHERE
    order_id = 20001 
GROUP BY
    order_products.order_id 
ORDER BY
    order_id DESC
```

Read more about GROUP BY modifier:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: I tried this and it works as query but when i use it in my PHP code i get this error on my page 

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.orders.order_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: so like orders.order_id, orders.customer_id etc?

Comment: Still getting the same error, is it maybe that im doing this at WHERE order_id > ? because i want to show all the orders bigger than 20000

Comment: The query works when you are executing it manually in phpmyadmin or Navicat?

Comment: The query gives this error when i run it from phpmyadmin #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.ordersorder_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Did you put in SELECT list the order_products.order_id column?

Comment: SELECT
    SUM(products.price * orders_products.quantity) AS total_order_price,
    orders.order_id, orderscustomer_id, orders.date_order_placed, orders.expiration_date, orders.status,
    customers.first_name, customersmiddle_name, customers.last_name
FROM
    orders
    LEFT JOIN orders_products USING ( order_id )
    LEFT JOIN products USING ( product_id )
    LEFT JOIN customers USING ( customer_id ) 
WHERE
    order_id > ?
GROUP BY
   orders_products.order_id 
ORDER BY
    order_id DESC this is what i have rn

Comment: When you are getting the error GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.orders.order_id' because the column order_id is not in the group by clause, just as it says. So it is saying that you are grouping some rows together and when the query tries to group the order_id column, it could having different values within the rows being grouped. The query does not know which one is the right value to show in the grouped row. - I edited the answer and modified the joins without USING().

Comment: By changing it and refine it finally works.

Comment: Nice! I am glad!

Comment: Can you mark the answer as Solved if it helped you? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT customers.customer_id, customers.first_name, 
       customers.last_name, customers.email,
       orders.order_id, orders.date_order_placed,
       SUM(products.price * orders_products.quantity) total_order_sum
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orders_products USING (order_id) 
LEFT JOIN products USING (product_id) 
LEFT JOIN customers USING (customer_id) 
/*
    WHERE orders.order_id = ?
or
    WHERE orders.order_id IN (?, ?, ...)
and also maybe
      AND customers.customer_id = ?
*/
GROUP BY customers.customer_id, customers.first_name, 
         customers.last_name, customers.email,
         orders.order_id, orders.date_order_placed
ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    date_order_placed,
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Customer,
    SUM(price) AS Total,
    status
FROM
    order_table
        LEFT JOIN
    o_product_table USING (order_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    product_table USING (product_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    c_table USING (customer_id)
WHERE
    order_id = 20001
ORDER BY order_id DESC;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code ?